# What is the logical reasoning behind the syntax of Closure block in Swift?

Tags: swift

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), the syntax of a Closure is as follows

```
{ (parameters) -> return type in
    statements
}
```

What is the logical reasoning behind putting the parameters and return type inside the curlies, instead of going with a more familiar function type syntax such as

```
 func name(parameters) -> return_type { 
        statements
    }
```

Comment: are you asking why use closure instead of named function? because it is unnamed function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closure syntax is the way it is to facilitate brevity in some common cases. Consider the named function syntax, if it were used for closures (obviously removing `name` since closures are anonymous function literals).

Rather than the current approach (in its most verbose form):

```
let f: (Type) -> ReturnType = { (parameter: Type) -> ReturnType in 
    return process(parameter)
}
```

it would be:

```
let f: (Type) -> ReturnType = func (parameter: Type) -> ReturnType { 
    return process(parameter)
}
```

This has a number of problems. First, closures can often infer their parameter and return types, so the syntax for that would be:

```
let f: (Type) -> ReturnType = func (parameter) { 
    return process(parameter)
}
```

This is starting to get a little confusing. Is this a function that returns Void, or a function that return ReturnType? In the standard named function syntax, leaving off the return type means Void, but here it's not quite so obvious. The compiler is certain; there'd be no ambiguity, but it's already deviating from named function syntax in subtle ways.

(It would have been more consistent to make all functions include their return type, but I think many Swift devs would be been upset to have to type `-> Void` so often. Or they could have had all functions have implicit return types, like in Scala, but they felt that hurt readability.)

Now consider the case when parameters are implicit and return assumed:

```
let f: (Type) -> ReturnType = func { process($0)}
```

This is a very, very common case. For example consider what it would do to `map`:

```
xs.map(func { process($0) })
```

I think the extra `func` here is just noise. `xs.map{ process($0) }` is nicer IMO.

A deeper question is why functions don't follow closure syntax. There would actually be a lot of benefits if there were no "methods" only function properties like:

```
struct Foo {
    let dothing = { (x: Int) -> Int in x * 2 }
}
```

rather than

```
struct Foo {
    func dothing(x: Int) -> Int { return x * 2 }
}
```

The fact that named functions are so special-cased is actually the weird thing about Swift, and it introduces a lot of headaches (like you can't use a function property to conform to a protocol, only a named function).

But providing the `func` syntax feels more natural to C, Java and JavaScript developers, which is why I suspect it's there. To ML and Scala developers, it's weird. But it wouldn't have worked nearly as well for closures.